# how to use gap.plot with reverse x axis?

Tags: r

I want to use `gap.plot` with a reverse x axis using `xlim=rev()` but it adds space around the plot making it larger.

Here is some data

```
x <- c(1:5, 6.9, 7)
y <- 2^x
```

`gap.plot` works perfecly with a normal x axis :

```
gap.plot(x, y, xlim=c(1,7), gap=c(5.3,6.6),type="b", xlab="index", ylab="value",gap.axis="x")
axis.break(1, 5.3, breakcol="snow", style="gap")
axis.break(1, 5.4, breakcol="black", style="slash")
axis.break(3, 5.4, breakcol="black", style="slash")
```

but is weird and adds space with a reverse x axis :

```
gap.plot(x, y, xlim=rev(c(1,7)), gap=c(5.3,6.6),type="b", xlab="index", ylab="value",gap.axis="x")
axis.break(1, 5.3, breakcol="snow", style="gap")
axis.break(1, 5.2, breakcol="black", style="slash")
axis.break(3, 5.2, breakcol="black", style="slash")
```

Is there a way to delete the space in the plot or another way to obtain the reverse x axis ?

thanks